# Was there a specific inspiration for the doom ray device in "LEGO Marvel Superheroes"?

Tags: marvel, galactus

In LEGO marvel superheroes, doctor doom uses the material from the silver surfer's board to create a weapon, but is there a reason it looks that way? I really like the design. And im also curious about where the idea that it could mind control galactus even came from. Unless of course that last thing was just because they made it into the last phase, and then just sort of ran out of ideas.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKCcFcN2AMg - The Doom Ray (of doom) just seems to be a pretty run-of-the-mill doom ray.

Comment: Now i have a new question, what was the creator of that video was smoking when he massacred all those innocent super_character files? Seriously though, i don't believe its just a run-of-the-mill doom ray because firstly its not even a ray, but a mind control device, and secondly, it actually has a unique design. I extracted the files from the game, and even 3d printed it (with wrong scale). Maybe im obsessed....